# C++ system() function header file

Tags: c++, system

for system() function in c++, which header file to be used in code::Blocks ? please help me !

Comment: Please ! I am a new  student in c++ programming

Comment: When in doubt look at the manual pages for the functions/classes. The headers usually are also mentioned there.

Comment: Please tell me details . i am new for that it has a problem to understand easily. PLease

Comment: What details is Hayt's comment missing? The reference page contains all the details **and** an example.

Comment: Thank you I got this <3 thank you so much <3

Comment: Stackoverflow is no tutorial. If you have specific questions ask them. Instead of answering I pointed you to a source to get the information and more if you need in the future.

Comment: #include <cstdlib>

Comment: What prevented you from looking this up?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include one of the 2 files below, which contain many C++ standard facilities:

```
#include <cstdlib>
//Or the c style header:
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: _"If not"_ No, you should always `#include` the headers you need, rather than guessing at whether they were already transitively included.

Comment: Well, for things like Visual Studio, when you write `system`, a dropdown menu shows saying if it is included or not... I will update my answer

Comment: That doesn't change anything. It's a bad practice, for several reasons.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I completely agree

Answer (score 1):

C++ has an international standard.

This means that the answer to (paraphrase) “which header to use for `system`?” does not depend on the compiler or IDE.

The standard costs money and is written for compiler writers, but the language and its standard library is documented for ordinary programmers over at [www.cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com).

Comment: Actually, `system` is in the C standard, but that too is the sort of details that only compiler vendors need to worry about. However, the practical consequence is that you can't pass a `std::string` directly, you need to call `std::string::c_str()` (short for "C style string")

Comment: @MSalters: I bet 100 rep the OP is using C strings anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Better put up a feature request on Meta. SO rep is a prime example of gamification in action, and rep betting is just extending that to multiplayer gaming ;)

Comment: @MSalters: They won't even let us trade rep, the philistines, so I doubt a gambling licence will be forthcoming ;)

Comment: @MSalters: The C standard library is "is incorporated into this International Standard by reference" (e.g. C++14 §17.5.1.5/1), and so it has been since C++98. As it happens the C++ standard mentions itself which header to use for the `system` function, namely "<cstdlib> (runtime environment getenv(), system())" in §18.10/1. Which in practice means, include `<stdlib.h>`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As @hayt mentioned early on, the first place to look is the command reference material, or the `man pages`, for functions/classes.  They often will mention the header file.

Googling for "system c++ reference" will lead you to here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Bing may also work in this case.

In the upper-right of the man page, it shows a `<cstdlib>`.  That's your huckleberry.